# Category adding issue using admin panel

Tags: magento2.3

I am adding categoty and its subcategory using catalog->category. Adding Category But Not visible in frontend. When I was inspect in browser it will be visible but not display in dropdown section.

Comment: Do you include the category in menu?

Answer (score 0):

I Use admin form Category select drop down at frontend

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

***module.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

we will add registration.php

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName**

***registration.php***

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

now create route file for frontend

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="test" id="test">
            <module name="VendorName_ModuleName"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

now create block which provide cetegory Option

**app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\Block**

***Test.php***

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $formKey;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Model\PageLayout\Config\BuilderInterface $pageLayoutBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->formKey = $context->getFormKey();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getCategoriesTree()
    {
        $categories = $this->_objectManager->create(
            'Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options'
        )->toOptionArray();
        return json_encode($categories);
    }
}
```

Now create Controller and action file

**app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Test**

***Index.php***

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Test;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory) {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

now create layout file

**app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout**

***test_test_index.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Ui Multi Select</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Test" name="ui_multiselect" template="test.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

now create template file

**app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\view\frontend\templates**

***test.phtml***

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('multiselect/manage/save', ['_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()]) ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label"><?php echo __('Select Category') ?>:</label>
            <div class="show-select" data-bind="scope: 'customCategory'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                    "*": {
                        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                            "components": {
                                "customCategory": {
                                    "component": "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select",
                                    "template" : "VendorName_ModuleName/ui-select",
                                    "filterOptions": true,
                                    "levelsVisibility": "3",
                                    "multiple": true,
                                    "showCheckbox": true,
                                    "options": <?php echo $block->getCategoriesTree()?>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

now we create template for this drop- down select

**app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\view\frontend\web\template**

***ui-select.html***

```
<!-- ko ifnot: disableLabel -->
<label class="admin__form-field-label" data-bind="attr: {for: uid}
">
    <span translate="label"></span>
</label>
<!-- /ko -->
<div class="admin__action-multiselect-wrap action-select-wrap" tabindex="0" data-bind="
attr: {
    id: uid
},
css: {
    _active: listVisible,
    'admin__action-multiselect-tree': isTree()
},
event: {
    focusin: onFocusIn,
    focusout: onFocusOut,
    keydown: keydownSwitcher
},
outerClick: outerClick.bind($data)
">
    <!-- ko ifnot: chipsEnabled -->
    <div class="action-select admin__action-multiselect" data-role="advanced-select" data-bind="
    css: {_active: multiselectFocus},
    click: function(data, event) {
        toggleListVisible(data, event)
    }
">
        <div class="admin__action-multiselect-text" data-role="selected-option" data-bind="text: setCaption()">
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: getSelected(), as: 'option'}  -->
        <input type="hidden" name="category_id" data-bind="
            attr: {
                id: 'wk-cat-hide'+value,
                value: value
            }
        ">
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: chipsEnabled -->
    <div class="action-select admin__action-multiselect" data-role="advanced-select" data-bind="
    css: {_active: multiselectFocus},
    click: function(data, event) {
        toggleListVisible(data, event)
    }
">
        <div class="admin__action-multiselect-text" data-bind="
        visible: !hasData(),
        i18n: selectedPlaceholders.defaultPlaceholder
">
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: getSelected(), as: 'option'}  -->
        <span class="admin__action-multiselect-crumb">
            <span data-bind="text: label">
            </span>
            <button class="action-close" type="button" data-action="remove-selected-item" tabindex="-1" data-bind="click: $parent.removeSelected.bind($parent, value)
        ">
                <span class="action-close-text" translate="'Close'"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div class="action-menu" data-bind="css: { _active: listVisible }
">
        <!-- ko if: filterOptions -->
        <div class="admin__action-multiselect-search-wrap">
            <input class="admin__control-text admin__action-multiselect-search" data-role="advanced-select-text" type="text" data-bind="
        event: {
            keydown: filterOptionsKeydown
        },
        attr: {id: uid+2},
        valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
        value: filterInputValue,
        hasFocus: filterOptionsFocus
        ">
            <label class="admin__action-multiselect-search-label" data-action="advanced-select-search" data-bind="attr: {for: uid+2}
    ">
            </label>
            <div if="itemsQuantity" data-bind="text: itemsQuantity" class="admin__action-multiselect-search-count">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <ul class="admin__action-multiselect-menu-inner _root" data-bind="
        event: {
            mousemove: function(data, event){onMousemove($data, event)}
        }
    ">
            <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option'}  -->
            <li class="admin__action-multiselect-menu-inner-item _root" data-bind="css: { _parent: $data.optgroup }" data-role="option-group">
                <div class="action-menu-item" data-bind="
                css: {
                    _selected: $parent.isSelected(option.value),
                    _hover: $parent.isHovered(option, $element),
                    _expended: $parent.getLevelVisibility($data),
                    _unclickable: $parent.isLabelDecoration($data),
                    _last: $parent.addLastElement($data),
                    '_with-checkbox': $parent.showCheckbox
                },
                click: function(data, event){
                    $parent.toggleOptionSelected($data, event);
                },
                clickBubble: false
        ">
                    <!-- ko if: $data.optgroup && $parent.showOpenLevelsActionIcon-->
                    <div class="admin__action-multiselect-dropdown" data-bind="
                    click: function(event){
                        $parent.openChildLevel($data, $element, event);
                    },
                    clickBubble: false
                 ">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /ko-->
                    <!--ko if: $parent.showCheckbox-->
                    <input class="admin__control-checkbox" type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" data-bind="attr: { 'checked': $parent.isSelected(option.value) }">
                    <!-- /ko-->
                    <label class="admin__action-multiselect-label">
                        <span data-bind="text: option.label"></span>
                        <span if="$parent.getPath(option)" class="admin__action-multiselect-item-path" data-bind="text: $parent.getPath(option)"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <!-- ko if: $data.optgroup -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: $parent.optgroupTmpl, data: {root: $parent, current: $data}} -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko-->
            </li>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
        <!-- ko if: $data.closeBtn -->
        <div class="admin__action-multiselect-actions-wrap">
            <button class="action-default" data-action="close-advanced-select" type="button" data-bind="click: outerClick">
                <span translate="closeBtnLabel"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now run commands

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento c:c
```

After creating all the above steps, you called the URL as http://domainname.com/test/test/index

here you have not see proper becuse you have to add adminhtml css to your frontend after you see like this.

[image]
Source [click here](https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-multi-select-ui-field-frontend-admin/)

***I Hope This Helps You.***