# Magento 2: How to add multiselect dropdown field on my Home Page

Tags: module, magento2.3, frontend, multiselect

I'm new in Magento 2 and I have created a custom module.  Now I want to add multi-select dropdown field in my module's front template on my home page.

How to add a multi-select dropdown, please?

Comment: please refer this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292828/category-adding-issue-using-admin-panel/293227#293227

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you want exact with a screenshot so we can provide the best solution.